# Django + skelJS / Static Files Issue / References to Images in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, django, static

**Edit: This problem was caused by skelJS, not Django. See answer.**

I'm fairly new to Django, but have read the docs, Google, and several StackOverflow topics and cannot seem to get static files working as intended.

When my template is rendered, the static paths are inserted correctly (e.g. {{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css is converted into static/css/style.css. I am able to navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css` in my browser.

The CSS works partially, but the images referenced in the CSS file are not being rendered. However, I can navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/images/bg02.jpg` (the body background image) without issue. Out of curiosity, I ran manage.py collectstatic, which populated my static folder with css/, js/, and image/, copied my (un-Django templated) index.html to that directory, opened it, and everything rendered properly. Furthermore, in style.css, I've used find and replace to change all occurrences of `images/*.jpg` to `static/css/images/*.jpg`, `css/images/*.jpg`, and simply `*.jpg` with no satisfaction (I've also confirmed these changes were being made by visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css` in my browser).

Any help you fine folks could offer would be much appreciated.

**Parent Template base_home.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/config.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
...
```

**Child Template home.html (called by view, extends base_home.html)**

```
#This is pretty plain, but I wanted to add/learn the functionality early
{% extends "base_home.html" %}

{% block headline %}Insert catchy headline here.{% endblock %}
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/config.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>

<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/skel-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style-desktop.css" />
</noscript>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="/static/js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

**settings.py**

```
...
STATIC_ROOT = 'E:/Projects/sandbox/website/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'E:/Projects/sandbox/website/resources',
    # This dir contains css/ images/ and js/
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
...
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from sandbox.context_processors import sitevars


def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[sitevars]))
```

**context_processors.py**

```
def sitevars(request):
    return {
        'meta_d': 'Meta description here',
        'meta_k': 'Meta keywords here',
        'title': 'HTML page title here',
        'logo': 'Text that needs to be inserted on pages',
        'copyright': r'HTML/text that needs to be inserted on pages'
    }
```

**style.css**

```
body
{
    background: #D4D9DD url('images/bg02.jpg');
}
...
.check-list li
{
    ...
    background: url('images/icon-checkmark.png') 0px 1.05em no-repeat;
}
...
.bordered-feature-image
{
    ...
    background: #fff url('images/bg04.png');
}
...
.custom-feature-image
{
    ...
    background: #fff url('images/bg05.png');
}
...
.item header
{
    ...
    background: #2b3336 url('images/bg01.jpg');
}
```

Comment: so `bg02.jpg` lives at `STATIC_ROOT/css/images/bg02.jpg`?

Comment: jproffitt, Yes | @toad013 See answer to jproffitt | After additional research, this appears to be caused by a javascript frontend framework I am using called skelJS. It is somehow dynamically applying CSS files and it is referencing css/ instead of static/css/. I am attempting to modify the code and will post the fix when completed.

As an alternative to modifying the code, would it just be possible to redirect all HTTP requests from css/ to static/css/ with urls.py? I'll look in to that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok folks, I was correct, this was not related to Django at all and for that I apologize.

For any readers who use skelJS...

After beautifying/de-minimizing the code, look for:

```
newStyleSheet: function (a) {
    var c = document.createElement("link");
    c.rel = "stylesheet";
    c.type = "text/css";
    c.href = a;
    return c
},
```

Then, replace `c.href = a;` with `c.href = "/static/" + a;` where "/static/" is your STATIC_URL defined in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths to your images. They are relative to where the css file lives. So, if a background-image declaration in STATIC_ROOT/css/style.css needs to reference bg02.jpg in STATIC_ROOT/images/bg02.jpg it should be declared like `background-image: url(../images/bg02.jpg)`